# How does a DE get notified about application crashes?

Tags: desktop-environment, crash

How does a desktop manager like `KDE` get notified that some program has crashed and is in the `Not responding` state ?

OK , after the program finished up , it can be deduced from the return code that possibly an error has occured , but consider the situation wherein a program is still in the execution phase but for example its event loop is blocked for some reason and doesn't respond to any input event.